# docx4j cant load file with error java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, docx4j

in my spring boot project iam using docx4j to load a file from the target folder although the file exists when i use system.out.print("exists) it appears in the console . any solution ? here is the code

```
 public void testDocx4j() throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException {
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:compare.docx");
    if(file.exists()){
      System.out.println("exists !!");
    }
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(file);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

  }
```

i was trying to load the file with docx4j

Comment: What package does your ResourceUtils come from?  Do you get a stack trace?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: actually there was a dependency missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
import org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils;

public class LoadAsResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException, IOException {

        InputStream is = ResourceUtils.getResource("sample-docxv2.docx");

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(is);
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();    
        
        System.out.println(documentPart.getXML());
    }

}
```